# Satchmo donations

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, satchmo

Can anyone share some pointers on building a Donations module for Satchmo? I'm comfortable customizing Satchmo's product models etc but unable to find anything related to Donations

I realize it's possible to create a Donations virtual product but as far as I can tell this still requires setting the amount beforehand ($5, $10 etc). I want users to be able to donate arbitrary amounts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the *satchmo_cart_details_query* signal is the way to go about doing this. It allows you to add a price change value (in my case, donation amount) to a cart item

I'll post the full solution if anyone is interested